# get random int from a set in python and how to improve performance

Tags: python, random, set

I actually use the following code to get a random int from a set. But this set is large so the random select is really slow. Is there any better way?

```
def getRandomBook():
    return int(random.sample(getBookSet(),1)[0])


def getBookSet(cleaned_sales_input = "data/cleaned_sales.csv"):
    with open(cleaned_sales_input, "rb") as sales_file:
        sales = csv.reader(sales_file)
        return {int(row[6]) for row in sales}
```

Comment: What's so slow is probably not the selecting, but that you re-read the CSV file every time you call your `getRandomBook()` function. If you need to call it more than once, consider rewriting your code so that you read the file only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the file only *once*, and turn the set into a list; the `random.sample()` implementation already turns a set into tuple just to be able to pick a sample. Avoid that overhead and just use `random.choice()` instead:

```
books = None

def getRandomBook():
    global books
    if books is None:
        books = list(getBookSet())
    return random.choice(books)
```

No need to call `int()` because you already converted the read values.

This at least speeds up picking a random value on *repeat* calls to `getRandomBook()`. If you need to call this only *once* per run of your program, there is no way around this other than creating a simpler file with just the unique book values.

Comment: Why the `random.sample` and `random.choice`? Can't he just call `random.choice` on whatever comes out of `getBookSet`, since he only wants one?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: The OP is using `random.sample()` because that function supports picking from a `set()` object, while `random.choice()` does not.

Comment: when i copie your code at the same point of mine, i get a strange error
Encountered "return" at line 340, column 5. Was expecting one of:     "(" ...     ")" ...     "[" ...     "," ...     "." 
 ...     "+" ...     "-" ...     "*" ...     "/" ...     "//" ...     "<<" ...     ">>" ...     "%" ...     "^" ...     "|" ...     "&" ...     ">" 
 ...     "<" ...     "==" ...     "<=" ...     ">=" ...     "<>" ...     "!=" ...     "or" ...     "and" ...     "not" ...     "is" ...     
 "in" ...     "if" ...     "for" ...     "," ...

Comment: @SvenBamberger: Syntax error on `return`? Yes, I forgot a closing parenthesis on the preceding line, corrected that now.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: Note that in order to achieve that, `random.sample()` simply calls `sample(tuple(setobject), count)`, turning the large set into a tuple *each time*. Not an efficient method.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that, but since you are already turning it into a list, couldn't it be `return random.choice(list(getBookSet()))`?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: How would that be faster? That would a) read the file each time you call `getRandomBook()` and then turn it into a list. Each time.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: My code *avoids* reading the file each time, and avoids turning the set into a list or tuple each time.

Comment: Ok, I had missed that part, I understand now.

Comment: books = list(random.sample(getBookSet()))
TypeError: sample() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
did i miss something here? ^^

Comment: Sorry, one last thing then, couldn't it be just `books = list((getBookSet())`?

Comment: @SvenBamberger: More mistakes on my part, all corrected. My apologies.

Comment: you don't need to apologies ^^ you are a human being it'S normal to make mistakes :-)